# Как сделать вывод из закольцованного цикла?

Tags: java, while

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что мне нужно возвращать значения из цикла каждую итерация. Дебаг показал, что цикл работает как нужно(через `System.out.print` в консоли все отображается как я хочу), но я хочу возвращать значения в рантайме, а не выводить в консоль

Вот мой код

```
    while (true) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < table.size()) {
            int j = i;
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                if (j == table.size()) {
                    j = 0;
                }
                try {
                    //В этом блоке происходит обращение к базе
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Подскажите, где должен быть `return`, чтобы возвращалась не одна запись, а все по очереди?

> Я очень начинающий, не судите строго :)

Comment: Можете ли вы, по условию вашей задачи добавлять в цикле ваши записи в коллекцию, например в список? Или вам обязательно нужно сделать так, чтобы один вызов - одна запись?

Comment: @СергейГурылёв все данные о вызове попадают в массив строк емкостью 4 и должны вывестись, затем массив заполняется новыми 4 записями и так далее

Comment: Если не трудно, можете полнее описать вашу задачу? Зачем вам бесконечный цикл while? Запрос делаете в СУБД? Скорее всего ваш код можно организовать чуть по-другому, чтобы добиться желаемой цели

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если i это строка в таблице , а j это поле, то ты явно переработал и тебе надо отдохнуть ибо у тебя сейчас каша в голове)

делается это примерно вот так, https://mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-statement-example-select-list-of-the-records/